# Does Microsoft SAPI lets you make a waveform of the words you speak?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, waveform, sapi

I am new to SAPI, please let me know if Microsoft SAPI lets you display a waveform of the words while one is still recording. 
OR
lets you make a a waveform of the entire words one spoke.

Any guidance in both directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what you want?   As it is now, it's unanswerably vague.

Comment: Thank you @EricBrown for the response. I figured out the way to do it. I will post the solution soon!
However, I wanted to display the waveform of the audio recognized by the MS api.

Comment: You never posted your solution.